# Scrapy go through all links

Tags: scrapy

I am using scrapy to crawl my whole page. Somehow the regular expressions are wrong.

Here my part:

```
def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.xpath('//li')
        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = CraigslistSampleItem()
            item["title"] = titles.xpath("a/text()").extract()
            item["link"] = titles.xpath("a/@href").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return(items)
```

I want to parse all links in `<li>` , get the URL and the anchor tag.

Comment: I don't see any regular expressions in your code

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to cast your `response` object to `HtmlXPathSelector` because it is per default -- only if you do some nasty things and load files and feed it to the `parse_items` function.

I would try

```
for title in titles:
    item = CraigslistSampleItem()
    item["title"] = title.xpath("./a/text()").extract()
    item["link"] = title.xpath("./a/@href").extract()
    items.append(item)
```

You use the `titles` variable too much: as the list containing your `li` tags and as the variable for each element. This is basically wrong. Use `title` as the variable in the loop.

However if you have multiple `a` tags in your HTML under a `li` you should think about a different method because you would get back a list of URLs and their titles.

Comment: shouldn't that be `item["title"] = title.xpath("./a/text()").extract()`?

Comment: Yes, should be, fixed this typo. It is always hard to handle copy-paste errors. And as I see the asker is no longer interested in the question.

Comment: They do that, at least you'll get a "Tenacious" badge!